# adding bullets to header tag in orchard

Tags: html, css, orchardcms

I created list in orchard and the h1 tag takes the title of the list. I need to add a bullet for the header.

I need bullet before the h1 tag like the below image

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/nRq27/1/

```
 <header>
    <h1>School info</h1>
  </header>
```

I used the background:image property, but its not displaying the bullet. how can I get the bullets?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4wLZ6/5/ check this fiddle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
h1:before {
    background-image: url(http://www.alexander-bown.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/big-black-dot.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    content:"";
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nRq27/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below css

```css
h1:before {
    content: '\2022';
    margin:0 10px  
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EXInugO/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><h1> School Info </h1> </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
   li
{
    list-style-type:square;
    font-size:small;
}
h1
{
 color: #3E5DA3;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

[Fiddle Demo Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4wLZ6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <h1> 
        <ul> 
            <li> School info </li>
         </ul>
    </h1>
</header>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qcXf/

Output will be

## - School info